# Fréchet Spaces is Cototal

Tags: category-theory

Let **Frek** denote the full-subcategory of **CTVS**, the category whose objects are complete locally convex spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and whose arrows are bounded linear maps.  Further, let **sFrek** denote the full-subcategory of **Frek** whose objects are separable Fréchet spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.

Are either of **Frek** or **sFrek** cototal?

Comment: These questions could use a bit more motivation and/or evidence of effort on your part. Have you tried to check whether Frek is complete and well-powered with a cogenerator?

Comment: Please also avoid duplicating postings on both MSE and MO.

Comment: Well it is cogenerated, with cogenerator $\mathbb{R}$.... actually I tried to show that its topological over $Vect_{\mathbb{R}}$ but had trouble doing so (as I havent done any category theory in about 6 years)....as for motivation... I've been casually browsing papers linking category theory and functional analysis :)